# Loop Optimisation: merge two loops into one

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the two loops below:

```
Dim intLstRowA As Integer
Dim intLstRowB As Integer

intLstRowA = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
intLstRowB = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To intLstRowA
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 22).Value2 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value2 * Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value2
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 23).Value2 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value2 * Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value2
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 24).Value2 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value2 * Sheets(1).Cells(i, 9).Value2
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 25).Value2 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value2 * Sheets(1).Cells(i, 19).Value2
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 26).Value2 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value2 * Sheets(1).Cells(i, 20).Value2
Next i
For i = 2 To intLstRowB
        Sheets(2).Cells(i, 22).Value2 = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value2 * Sheets(2).Cells(i, 5).Value2
        Sheets(2).Cells(i, 23).Value2 = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value2 * Sheets(2).Cells(i, 6).Value2
        Sheets(2).Cells(i, 24).Value2 = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value2 * Sheets(2).Cells(i, 9).Value2
        Sheets(2).Cells(i, 25).Value2 = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value2 * Sheets(2).Cells(i, 19).Value2
        Sheets(2).Cells(i, 26).Value2 = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value2 * Sheets(2).Cells(i, 20).Value2
Next i
```

There is two loops because intLstRowA is different than intLstRowB (usually the difference is from 20 to 50), otherwise I would have added a "j" value (from 1 to 2) to loop between Sheets(1) and Sheets(2).

Any idea?

Comment: You can always put `intLstRow` to an array and iterate it using `j` (i.e. `intLstRowA` would be `intLstRow[0]`) ,

Comment: Thank you everyone! All your answers are really good, but the one by Jeeped what was I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about as tight as I can get it.

```
Dim i As Long, v As Long, s As Long, vCOLs As Variant

vCOLs = Array(Array(22, 23, 24, 25, 26), Array(5, 6, 9, 19, 20))

For s = 1 To 2
    With Sheets(s)
        For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For v = LBound(vCOLs(1)) To UBound(vCOLs(1))
                .Cells(i, vCOLs(0)(v)) = .Cells(i, 4).Value2 * .Cells(i, vCOLs(1)(v)).Value2
            Next v
        Next i
    End With
Next s
```

This works by putting both rank of a two dimensional array to work supplying the column index numbers for the source and target of the computation.

Will compile but not field tested against sample data.

Comment: Does shortens the code significantly as requested - side comment though is this comes with the cost of retaining the range loop.

Comment: @brettdj - Agreed that using blocks of formulas and converting to their values would be more efficient. I'd be interested in seeing some timed results but I am reluctant to create 50,000 or so rows of sample data.

Comment: It returns Runtime Error 9 Subscript Out of Range :( Any idea why? I only have 2000 rows.

Comment: What line is it returning that error on? Surely you have two worksheets and the worksheets will have more than 26 columns each.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 worksheets, with more than 26 columns :) The line is: Cells(i, vCOLs(v, 1)) = .Cells(i, 4).Value2 * .Cells(i, vCOLs(v, 2)).Value2

Comment: @clippertm - I had some bad syntax that had passed the compiler but wasn't working well with real data. Please see revisions above.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a second sub (to remove) the duplication, and with ranges to remove loops, ie:

```
Sub Recut()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lngLstRowA As Long
Dim lngLstRowB As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

lngLstRowA = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lngLstRowB = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Call Update(ws1, lngLstRowA)
Call Update(ws2, lngLstRowB)

End Sub

Sub Update(ws As Worksheet, lngRow As Long)

With ws
    Range(.Cells(2, 22), .Cells(lngRow, 22)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC4*RC5"
    Range(.Cells(2, 23), .Cells(lngRow, 23)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC4*RC6"
    Range(.Cells(2, 24), .Cells(lngRow, 24)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC4*RC9"
    Range(.Cells(2, 25), .Cells(lngRow, 25)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC4*RC19"
    Range(.Cells(2, 26), .Cells(lngRow, 26)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC4*RC20"
    Range(.Cells(2, 22), .Cells(lngRow, 26)).Value = Range(.Cells(2, 22), .Cells(lngRow, 26)).Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I was about to post the same approach without a loop :)

Answer (score 1):

If some piece of code is used more than once, it's good practice to move into separate function/procedure, for example:

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal wsh As Worksheet)
    Dim intLastRow As Integer

    inLastRow = wsh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To intLstRowA
            wsh.Cells(i, 22).Value2 = wsh.Cells(i, 4).Value2 * wsh.Cells(i, 5).Value2
            wsh.Cells(i, 23).Value2 = wsh.Cells(i, 4).Value2 * wsh.Cells(i, 6).Value2
            wsh.Cells(i, 24).Value2 = wsh.Cells(i, 4).Value2 * wsh.Cells(i, 9).Value2
            wsh.Cells(i, 25).Value2 = wsh.Cells(i, 4).Value2 * wsh.Cells(i, 19).Value2
            wsh.Cells(i, 26).Value2 = wsh.Cells(i, 4).Value2 * wsh.Cells(i, 20).Value2
    Next i
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
Dim sh as Worksheet
Dim i as Integer

For i = 1 to 2
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet(i)
    DoSomething sh
Next
```

Summary:
1. code is optimized (only one `for... next` loop is written instead of two)
2. code works in context (changes are made in workbook where code is stored, not in active workbook)

I do not see other option to "optimize" your code into single `for...next` loop.